Unable to import csv in codeigniter 4
I am trying to import a CSV file into MySQL using CodeIgniter 4, but I'm facing an issue. When I printed my query, I noticed some dummy text before the column names, like:

INSERT INTO tbl_user (.ApplicationNo) VALUES ('123XXX');

This is causing me to be unable to save records to the table.
<?php
$file = $this->request->getFile("file");

if ($file->isValid() && !$file->hasMoved()) {
    $newName = $file->getRandomName();

    $uploadPath = ROOTPATH . "uploads/";
    if (!is_dir($uploadPath)) {
        mkdir($uploadPath, 0777, true);
    }
    $file->move($uploadPath, $newName);

    $csvFilePath = $uploadPath . $newName;
    $file = fopen($csvFilePath, "r");
    $data = [];
    $headers = fgetcsv($file);
    $headers = array_map("trim", $headers);
    while (($row = fgetcsv($file)) !== false) {
        // Trim whitespace from each row value
        $row = array_map("trim", $row);
        
        // Create associative array combining headers and current row
        $rowData = array_combine($headers, $row);
        

        // Add row data to the data array
        $data[] = $rowData;
    }
    fclose($file);
    
    $appModel->insertBatch($data);
    
    unlink($csvFilePath);

    return $adminModel->jsonResponse(true, SAVE_SUCCESS);
}
return $adminModel->jsonResponse(true, "Invalid file");

